# R function that takes in CL argument and queries SQL database

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

Brand new to SQL and SQLite here. I'm trying to create a function in R studio that takes in an argument from the command line and queries an SQL database to see if the record exists in one specific column, displaying a message to the user whether the record was found or not (I have a table within this database, lets call it my_table, that has 2 columns, we'll name them column_1 and column_2. column_1 has ID numbers and column_2 has names that are associated with those ID numbers, and there are a total of about 700 rows).

So far I have something that looks like this:

`my_function() <- function(CL_record) { db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "mysql.db") dbGetQuery(db, sql("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_2 == @CL_record")) }`

But this is obviously not the right way to go about it and I keep getting errors thrown regarding invalid (NULL) left side of assignment.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries). Also, you likely want to add `on.exit(dbDisconnect(db),add=TRUE)` before your `dbGetQuery`, otherwise your DBAs might become frustrated with you, and you need to be on their good side :-)

Comment: (And of course, that DBA comment was generic, not really a factor with SQLite :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries), something like:

```r
my_function <- function(CL_record) {
  db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "mysql.db")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(db), add = TRUE)
  dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_2 = ?",
             params = list(CL_record))
}
```

The `params=` argument does not need to be a `list(.)`, it works just fine here as `params=CL_record`, but if you have two or more, and especially if they are of different classes (strings vs numbers), then you really should `list` them.

You'll see many suggestions, or even howtos/tutorials that suggest using `paste` or similar for adding parameters to the query. There are at least two reasons for *not* using `paste` or `sprintf`:

1. Whether malicious or inadvertent (e.g., typos), [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is something that should be actively avoided. Even if your code is not public-facing, accidents happen.
2. Most (all?) DBMSes have query optimization/compiling. When it receives a query it has not seen before, it parses and attempts to optimize the query; when it sees a repeat query, it can re-use the previous optimization, saving time. When you `paste` or `sprintf` an argument into a query, each query is different from the previous, so it is overall less efficient. When using bound parameters, the query itself does not change (just its parameters), so we can take advantage of the compiling/optimization.